# MATLAB - "clear -except a" only deletes a

Tags: matlab

Everywhere I look it says that the expression clear `-except a` should clear all variables except for `a`. However, if I try it (MATLAB R2014a, running on Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit), matlab clears only the variable `a` ("-except a" is shown in purple, apparently being processed as a string). I tried `clear('-except a')`, which does not do anything, and 'clear - except a' - with a space between "-" and "except", which results in an error (too many arguments).

What am I doing wrong?

[edit]

Here are the full errors I obtain for `clearvars`:

```
EDU>> a = 5;
EDU>> clearvars -except a;
Error using strjoin (line 14)
Expected input to be one of these types:

char

Instead its type was cell.

Error in clearvars>createPattern (line 187)
    pattern = sprintf('(%s)$', strjoin(variableArgs, '|'));

Error in clearvars (line 76)
    exceptVarPat = sprintf('(?!%s)', createPattern(exceptVarArgs, flags.regexpExcept));
```

Comment: Try `clearvars` instead of `clear`.

Comment: Also gives an error (wrong input type, expected char)

Comment: `clearvars -except a`? It works for me (Matlab 2013b).

Comment: yes I know, it's what all the documentation says (including mine), but for some reason "-except" is considered a string (the error I get comes from function `strjoin`)

Comment: `clearvars -except a` also works for me in R2014a and R2014b. Strange. Can you post the full stack trace? Maybe check to see if you're overloading `clear` or `clearvars` using [`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I posted the error I get in an edit; what do you mean precisely by stack trace? Calling `dbstack` directly after the error does not return anything. `which clearvars` gives the path to "clearvars.m".

Comment: May be you have your own strjoin. Try "which strjoin".

Comment: `which strjoin` returns the path to a plugin file (or rather, a dependency of an external directory of a plugin of EEGLAB...), so that may be the problem? How can I reset this? And is there a way to make sure such that, generally, plugin files don't overwrite standard matlab functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurred because of a file named "strjoin.m" in the PropertyGrid package (that I had as a dependency of BCILab, an external package inside SIFT, a plugin for EEGLAB). Because of the [function precedence order in MATLAB](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html), this function was called instead of the function located in matlab/toolbox/strfun/strjoin.m. Renaming the plugin file solved the problem.

(Although I am not sure if this is the best solution, as it brings up the possibility for future bugs when PropertyGrid calls `strjoin`. In this case I think I will be fine, but comments on the best approach in similar situations would be appreciated).

Comment: The best way would be to patch the PropertyGrid package and rename `strjoin` everywhere in that package.

Comment: I recommend to contact the developers.

Comment: my error is 

??? Undefined function or method 'strjoin' for
input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==> test at 3
    load(strjoin(dataset(i)));

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively you can use regular expressions for that. For instance, if you have variables containing the word "path", you can clear all, excluding those by calling:

```
clear -regexp ^((?!path).)*$; % do not clear paths
```